# Firefox WebAudio API

Tags: api, firefox, audio

Can't process Audio Data via createAnalyser. When remote audio stream is connected to the analyser sound gets muted or no playback. Is this ever going to get fixed, kind of frustrating

Answer (score 0):

You can see a complete example with remote audio and createAnalyser here:
http://git.io/vegtp

```
var audioData = ajaxRequest.response;
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext)();
audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData ...
var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
```

With stream source: http://git.io/vegmk

```
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createAnalyser

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was a bit unclear on my post. Unlike chrome, firefox has CORS restriction when connecting audio source to the analyser. If it detects the req. and stream source are not the same domain it mutes the sound. I have not tried your approach yet but will post the result.